# Swift file URL get subpath

Tags: ios, swift, swift5, nsurl

Given an absolute file path such as

```
  /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B1296A55-8C0B-4276-BF95-E7D91220703B/Library/Projects/Project1/Image1.jpeg
```

I want to subtract the initial Library folder path and return

```
  Projects/Project1/Image1.jpeg
```

What is the best Swift function to return subpath after a given prefix in a fileURL?

Answer (score 1):

I would just use the string functions, such as:

```
  let fullpath = "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B1296A55-8C0B-4276-BF95-E7D91220703B/Library/Projects/Project1/Image1.jpeg"
  let result = fullpath.split(separator: "/").suffix(3).joined(separator: "/")
  print("\n---> result: \(result) \n")  // Projects/Project1/Image1.jpeg
```

or if you want to define the Library folder path:

```
  var thePrefix = "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B1296A55-8C0B-4276-BF95-E7D91220703B/Library/"
  let path = fullpath.replacingOccurrences(of: thePrefix, with: "")
  print("\n---> path: \(path)" )
```